# What is specific to an unevictable page?

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel

I was browsing the ramfs code and was puzzled by the notion of unevictable pages.

I've been reading the kernel's documentation at Documentation/vm/unevictable-lru.txt and this answer:

[unevictable page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343249/unevictable-page/4343338#4343338)

but it did not fully answer my question. It said that the kernel "cannot touch it" or "cannot evict it", but what does that mean ?

I thought that anyways, once a page is being used it could not be removed until it is volontarily released ? Or does it mean that it cannot be moved to swap ? Or is there some kind of a cache involved, outside of the ram, containing all of the unevictable pages ?

When building my own virtual filesystem, do I have to mark my inodes as unevictable ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "evict" means to re-purpose the page: i.e. free it up from its existing use and make it available for a different use. For pages that are used by user-space processes (with the exceptions you noted), the kernel keeps a least-recently-used ordered list of pages. If a process needs a page and no unused ones are available, the kernel will attempt to evict the least recently used page. That can mean:

- writing the page to swap space if dirty and not backed by a file,
- writing it out to a file if it's from an mmap'd file (and *not* locked),
- just "dropping" it if it's clean and is already up-to-date on
  the backing medium (for example, non-dirty page or clean executable
  code backed by on-disk executable file)

The corresponding page table entry for the old process (from which the page was stolen) are then marked not-present, and the physical page is now available for re-use by the new process.

If at a later time, the process (or processes) to which the original page belonged attempt to access it again, this will cause a not-present page fault, and the process starts all over again, with the kernel possibly evicting some other physical page, reading the data back in, etc.

Some pages are unevictable for the reasons you saw: either they are being used for kernel data, or they are part of a ramdisk (writing those to swap would defeat the purpose of a ramdisk), or have been "manually" locked in place by some other mechanism.

Your filesystem can either implement the "address space handler" protocol (see Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt) as do most filesystems, or it can allocate memory in such a way that they won't be swap candidates, depending on what makes the most sense for your particular functionality.